# Problems with SQL Server table indexing

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

`Subject` table:

```
Id int
DepartmentId int
GroupId int
SchoolId int
Name varchar(255)
```

**Queries**

Query #1

```
SELECT * 
FROM [Subject] t1, [Department] t2 
WHERE t1.DepartmentId = t2.DepartmentId
```

Query #2

```
SELECT * 
FROM [Subject] t1, [Group] t2, [Department] t3 
WHERE t1.GroupId = t2.GroupId 
  AND t1.SchoolId = t3.DepartmentId
```

Query #3

```
SELECT * 
FROM [Subject] t1, [Group] t2, [School] t3 
WHERE t1.GroupId = t2.GroupId 
  AND t1.SchoolId = t3.SchoolId
```

Should I create a 3 indexes for table "subject", or just one is enough?

Solution 1

Create one index: `departmentId + GroupId + SchoolId`

Solution 2

Create three indexes:

1. `DepartmentId` for stored proc 1.
2. `DepartmentId + GroupId` for stored proc 2.
3. `GroupId + SchoolId` for stored proc 3.

Thank you so much!

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution #1 will **not** work for query #3 - if you have a compound index on `(departmentId, groupId, SchoolId)`, your query #3 will definitely not be able to use that (since it doesn't use `departmentId` as a criteria). A compound index **only** works if you use **all n leftmost** columns.

What you *could* do is a mix between your solutions:

Create **two** indexes:

- one index on `DepartmentId, GroupId` which will be useful for queries #1 and #2
- another index on `GroupId, SchoolId` for query #3

But be cautious: **don't overindex!** Too many indices is worse than none at all.

Run your system - observe it's performance. If it's fast enough - be happy, go on a vacation!

Only if it's **not** fast enough, use performance profiling to find the worst performing queries, and add indices to handle those. Don't just put indices on every query you have - keeping those indices nice and shiny **also** costs you performance when you insert, update and delete data.

Comment: thanks for your answer! I understand now. one more question is should I include the columns exists in order by ?

Comment: @RickyYip: order by is sorting - and that's quite an expensive operation - so yes, it is definitely worth a try to see if having an index on the columns in the `order by` helps improve performance. But as I said: **don't overindex!**